# Android Editbox with Border, Image and Hint

Tags: android, styles, editbox

I am new to android. I want to make login screen design with as [image]

If anyone can help me out creating this type of Editbox with a White border and image at left inside that border and hint text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this to create bordered edittext

create borderedEdittext.xml and placed into drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Background Color -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <!-- Border Color -->
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff9900" />

    <!-- Round Corners -->
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

and for image and hint use this

```
<EditText
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/profilePic"
            android:hint="Enter Name"
            android:background="@drawable/borderedEdittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```